# Can an input button in my RShiny app automatically redirect me to a new page in my app, where I will see tables from yfinance?

Tags: shiny, datatable

I've been trying to create an Rshiny app which allows me to harness data from yfinance (installed via Python using the Reticulate function) on companies' quarterly financials. On my main page, I have an input box and a ticker table. Whenever I input a stock ticker into the input box, it is added to the ticker table. I also have a button called "Create Datablock", which, when pressed, extracts quarterly data from yahoo finance for all the tickers in the ticker table. For now, the app simply prints the quarterly financials tables for all the companies in the R console. I want the Create Datablock button (when pressed) to redirect me to a new page, within the same app, where my tables on quarterly financials will be displayed, instead of the R console. Is there a way to do this? Here is my code for reference:

```R
source("server.R", local = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1("Securities Analytical Intelligence", align = "center")), # Add align = "center"
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Create an input bar with an id
      autocomplete_input("new_ticker", "Enter Ticker", us_tickers, placeholder = "Type to search..."),
      actionButton("add_ticker", "Add Ticker"),
      actionButton("create_datablock", "Create Datablock")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("ticker_table")# Updated table output
    )
  )
)
# Get ticker symbols for the US market
us_tickers <- stockSymbols()$Symbol

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Create an SQLite database connection
  con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "tickers.db")
  
  # Create the 'tickers' table if it doesn't exist
  dbExecute(con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tickers (ticker TEXT)")
  
  # Load data from the database
  ticker_data <- reactiveValues(tickers = data.frame(ticker = character()))
  
  # Function to load data from the database and update the reactiveValues
  load_tickers <- function() {
    ticker_data$tickers <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM tickers")
  }
  
  # Load data initially
  load_tickers()
  
  # Add a new ticker
  observeEvent(input$add_ticker, {
    new_ticker <- input$new_ticker
    if (nchar(new_ticker) > 0) {
      dbExecute(con, sprintf("INSERT INTO tickers (ticker) VALUES ('%s')", new_ticker))
      load_tickers()  # Reload data from the database
    }
  })
  
  # Delete a ticker when a cell is clicked
  observeEvent(input$ticker_table_cell_clicked, {
    info <- input$ticker_table_cell_clicked
    if (!is.null(info$value) && info$col == ncol(ticker_data$tickers)) {
      ticker_to_delete <- info$value
      dbExecute(con, sprintf("DELETE FROM tickers WHERE ticker = '%s'", ticker_to_delete))
      load_tickers()  # Reload data from the database
    }
  })
  
  # Render the table output with the selected tickers
  output$ticker_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(ticker_data$tickers, options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE), colnames = c("Ticker"))
  })
  # Function to execute Python code for each ticker
  execute_python_code <- function(tickers) {
    
    for (ticker in tickers) {
      py_run_string(paste0("
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# Set the display option for maximum columns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

# Create a Ticker object for respective ticker
", ticker, " = yf.Ticker('", ticker, "')

hist = ", ticker, ".history(period = '3mo')

# Get the quarterly financial data for the ticker
", ticker, "_financials = ", ticker, ".quarterly_financials
"))
      
      # Access the financial data dataframe in R
      assign(paste0(ticker, "_financials"), py[[paste0(ticker, "_financials")]])
      
      # Print the first few rows of the dataframe
      print(get(paste0(ticker, "_financials")))
    }
  }
  # Event handler for the "Create Datablock" button
  observeEvent(input$create_datablock, {
    # Save the current table data
    # You may need to adjust this part based on how you want to save the table data
    
    # Extract tickers from the table
    tickers <- ticker_data$tickers$ticker
    
    # Execute Python code for each ticker
    execute_python_code(tickers)
    
    # Present extracted data in a nice table on a new page
    # You can implement this part based on your preference
    showModal(modalDialog(
      h3("Extracted Financial Data"),
      # Include the extracted data table here
    ))
  })
}
```

I tried various options presented to me by chatGPT, but all of them resulted in errors.

Comment: You don't want to use tab panels? If you want an app with multiple pages, see the **shiny.router** package. I also heard about the **brochure** package.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Sure I'll try that out! Do you know if there is any way for me to get the quarterly financials tables for the companies in my ticker table, from yfinance onto the new page though?  Thanks.